# How do I enable VT-x on my PC for Android Studio?

Tags: vt-x

I have Windows-10 but monitor is old. Intel(r)LG
I wanted to enable VT-x (virtualisation) on my pc pls help!!
[[image: This is my bios main settings.And there are other settings photos also...][1]]
[image][image]
[image][image][image]

I am not able to find the thing anywhere here! So please HELP!
THANK YOU..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CPU is too old to support VT-x.
See: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/35348/intel-core-2-duo-processor-e7200-3m-cache-2-53-ghz-1066-mhz-fsb.html

Comment: OK Thank you for your answer!